# Ruleset.xml - keytool and certificates

Tags: java, security, keytool

I am trying to understand how keytool work.

I have few questions:

- Question about Keytool: If we use keytool (keygen) using exact same details (DN/password .. etc) on two different machines, will we end up with identical keys?
- Question about ruleset.xml and DeploymentRuleSet.jar (Java 1.7 security): If we use self signed certificates, and import those certificates on client machines, will that resolve the issues of pop up warning that are getting nastier and nastier with each Java upgrade (now 1.7.0_45 is giving even worse warnings)

Comment: Try to keep to only one question within each question; so they can be answered individually

Answer (score 0):

1. Public/private key pairs are randomly seeded. You will not get the same keys on two machines using the same input.
2. Java has its own certificate store. Yes, if you import your self-signed certificate into client's key store, and app is signed properly, you should not get too nasty warnings.